# Select only the first two rows of a group meeting a specified condition

Tags: sql, oracle

My Table Structure:

```
ID   Name   Code
----------------
124  John   ABC
456  Jake   YQA
857  James  ABC
745  Jones  IUJ
878  Jared  YQA
989  Jimmy  HIJ
900  Jess   ABC
988  Jessi  YQA
```

and so on like this......

I want to select first two rows having Code as ABC and YQA

I need the output as below:

```
ID   Name   Code
----------------
124  John   ABC
857  James  ABC
456  Jake   YQA
878  Jared  YQA
```

In simpler words pls, since i am a newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`, and select the earliest 2 records for the `ABC` and `YQA` codes, as ordered by the `ID`.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITITON BY Code ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM yourTable t
    WHERE Code IN ('ABC', 'YQA')
)

SELECT ID, Name, Code
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY Code, Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

use row_number

```
 with t as 
    (select *, 
         row_number()  over (partition by survey) as idx 
     from table 
     where code in ('ABC','YQA')) 
select id, name, code from t where idx < 3;
```